# Pass code behind variable value to jQuery function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am not an expert in jQuery and I am trying to pass some variable values from C# to my function called on keyup and onclick events. So far I have something like this:

```
$('mydiv').bind('keyup click', function(event) {}
```

but what I need should be:

```
$('mydiv').bind('keyup click', function(event, UserId, ControlId) {}
```

, where UserId and ControlId are some ids I am getting in code behind from the query string. I am also using jQuery 1.6.4.

How can I do this, preferably without using hidden input fields?
Thank you.

Comment: What are UserId & ControlId supposed to represent? Which kind of data are you trying to pass to jQuery? Can you give a example with sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Use `on` instead of `bind`

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Passing values from the server to the client with razor (if youre using asp.net mvc):

```
$('mydiv').on('keyup click', function(event, @UserId, @ControlId) {}
```

or if its webforms:

```
$('mydiv')
    .on('keyup click', function(event, <%= UserId %>, <%= ControllId %>) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use data-attributes:

```
$('mydiv').data({ userId: <%= UserId %>, ControllId: <%= ControllId %> })
```

then you can access those data in the on click event:

```
$('mydiv').on('click', function(event) {
  var userId = $(this).data('userId');
  var ControlId = $(this).data('ControlId');
});
```

Comment: Use a property map instead of calling the data method multiple times. And why should he save it as data attributes in teh first place? He can access them directly from anywhere in his javascript anyway.

Comment: @Johan You are right. I missunderstood Christa23's question. The problem he had was how to access variables passed from c# to JavaScript. I think data-attributes are more clean than using global variables in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, I agree about the global variable part. But what im trying to say is that the values doesnt need to be saved in to varuables at all. They can already be accessed from anywhere using `<%= UserId %>`. And regarding your code snippet, imo, change it to `$('mydiv').data({ userId: <%= UserId %>, ControllId: <%= ControllId %> })`

Answer (score 0):

declare the variable as public in code behind

```
public string userId="abc";
```

Access it on client side

```
var uid='<%=userId %>';
$('mydiv').bind('keyup click', function(event, uid, ControlId) {}
```

Comment: As a side note, `public` is valid, but I would use `protected`accesor which is also valid as long as the scope seems to be only the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

A js file cannot directly access C# objects so you need to do something like below.
Even if you want to write complete jQuery code in your view file, you can still follow same approach.

So you can pass variables in some Model which is passed to View and once you have those variables in Model you can do something like below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var myList= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.UsersList));      
</script>
```

So now you have a json object which can be accessed by any individual js file as well with in same view file with the help of variable "myList".

Answer (score -1):

Javascript scopes are not like scopes in other languages
so if you write

```
var UserId = 5; 
var ControlId = 5;

$('mydiv').bind('keyup click', function(event) 
{
  alert( UserId );  
});
```

it will work

check out http://jsfiddle.net/FgYTL/1/

Answer (score -2):

Is my mydiv a class, id or a jQuery variable? Looks like you need to do

```
$('div.mydiv') or $('div#mydiv')
```